# Different launch screen on first launch (iOS 10+)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, user-experience

[Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/) state that a Launch Screen should be nearly identical to the first screen of your app.

In our app if the user is launching the app for the first time they are presented with an on-boarding/login screen that is considerably different to the main screen of the application.

Is there a way to set the default launch screen to be the "empty" version of our on-boarding screen and then once the user has logged in change the launch screen to be an "empty" version of the main screen?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: @luk2302 so the best option here would be to just show the main screen version of the launch screen as that is what the user will see 99% of the time and just take a hit on the UX for first launch?

Comment: probably, or do something similar to twitter where you basically have an animation as the first thing that transitions from a generic bird launch screen to whatever is supposed to be displayed afterwards.

Comment: Though in doing that, Twitter's splash screen would be going against the HIG's recommendation of not using the splash screen as an opportunity for branding. 

Comment: So what!? You have to choose whichever is the lesser evil for you...